# How to get reference of sibling components or other components in the DOM tree in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<App>
  <Header/>
  <Content/>
</App>
```

If I have above structure in a react App and i what to calculate the height of the `<Content/>` component by `window.innerHeight - <Header/>` height?
What is the ideal solution? Do I have to set the state on  component and pass update function as the prop to  component?
Also is there a way to get any component in the DOM/VirtualDOM tree, in any component?
I know we can use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`, but we need to pass refs or component itself. Is there any other way like `document.getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: I would look into using `react-measure` from your parent and pass the measured values as props to the children.

Answer (score 2):

There is no proper way (i.e. way that isn't an antipattern) to pass information directly between sibling components. As you suggested, I think your best bet would be to store this information as state on the parent component and pass down a function as props to the children that will update this state.

Comment: In this kind of scenarios, redux comes in?

Comment: Redux would definitely be useful for something like this and would perfectly solve this problem. Although, if your project is small enough and you only find yourself having to use this pattern once, I don't think redux would be necessary. Redux has a lot of overhead that might not make it worth it for a small project.